# Javascript Function executes..without being invoked?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

```
<a onclick="determineCountry(data)" class="installbtn">Install</a>
```

What I am trying to do:
When the button above is clicked, the user is redirected to one of three sites depending on his/her location. However, the script below is being executed immediately and redirects the user as soon as the page loads and NOT when the button is clicked (as intended). What am I doing wrong? Help me fix this, please.

```
<script>
function determineCountry(data){
   switch(data.address.country_code){
      case "US" :
         window.location.href = "https://www.usa.com";
      break;
      case "GB" :
         window.location.href = "https://www.gb.com";
      break;
      default :
         window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
   }    
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=determineCountry></script>
```

Comment: `?callback=determineCountry` in the wipmania.com script you're including calls the function...

Comment: You got an unclosed string literal in the "US" case; that shouldn't be causing this, but it can't be healthy.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's obviously just a copying error, or his function wouldn't run at all.

Comment: Edited. So.. basically there's no way of fixing it and making it run as I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line loads a JSONP website. JSONP works by having the server send back Javascript that calls a function. When you specify `callback=determineCountry`, that tells it to put a call to that function in the Javascript. So the script at the end contains a top-level call like:

```
determineCountry({ some JSON object });
```

When you load the script, it runs the function immediately.

Usually JSONP is used in AJAX calls, not directly in `<script>` tags. So you probably just want to remove the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=determineCountry></script>
```

Actually, what it looks like you really need to do is perform a JSONP AJAX call when the user clicks on the anchor:

```
<a onclick="ajaxDetermineCountry();" href="#" class="installbtn">Install</a>

<script>
function ajaxDetermineCountry() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=determineCountry";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
function determineCountry(data){
   switch(data.address.country_code){
      case "US" :
         window.location.href = "https://www.usa.com";
        break;
      case "GB" :
         window.location.href = "https://www.gb.com";
        break;
      default :
         window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
   }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think what you really need to do is have `determineCountry` perform the AJAX call.

Comment: Uh.. and how would I do that?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Hats off.